# zipWith Function Implemented Using Map and Zip Functions

Tags: list, haskell, syntax, syntax-error

I am attempting to implement the `zipWith` function via the `zip` and `map` functions, but I am getting an error that reads: "error: parse error on input '::' My code is below and and I am unsure of what I have done wrong

```
zipWith` :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
zipWith` f x y = zip x $ map f y
```

Comment: The backtick, `\``, is not a valid character for a variable name.  Also, why is `enter` there? Is that a typo or do you actually have the word `enter` in your source?  It doesn't belong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to use `'` symbol and not `` ` `` ; then, to combine the function you need to use `uncurry`:

```
zipWith' :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
zipWith' f xs ys  = map (uncurry f) (zip xs ys)
```

why is that, well the type of `zip` is:

```
zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]
```

but the function `f` is `f :: (a -> b -> c)`, so, with the help of `uncurry`,

```
uncurry :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a, b) -> c
```

you can map the function `f` into the `[(a, b)]`, transforming it into `[c]`.

Comment: For maximal inscrutability: `(<$> zip) <$> (<$>) <$> (<$>) <$> uncurry`

Comment: I don't know why you edited the question a couple hours ago, but it invalidated the answers (including your own!) so I rolled that back.

Comment: @dfeuer nice one, inscrutable at all but interesting as well! Thanks for the comments, and you're right also with the roll back

Comment: @dfeuer care to explain? Would be amusing to learn. Might also be enlightening.

Answer (score 2):

As Damian points out, `` zipWith` ``  doesn't work with the trailing backtick -- the backtick has a special meaning in Haskell. Rename it to `zipWith'`.

```
zipWith' :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
```

Then of course you have to actually *write* the solution. With explicit recursion you've got

```
zipWith' _ _ []          = []
zipWith' _ [] _          = []
zipWith' f (x:xs) (y:ys) = f x y : zipWith' f xs ys
```

but using `map` and `zip` you could apply it like this:

```
zipWith' f xs ys = map (\(x,y) -> f x y) . zip xs $ ys
```

or more easily-read:

```
zipWith' f xs ys = map (\(x,y) -> f x y) zipped
    where zipped = zip xs ys
```